# Serve lit component with vite through my own cli in nodejs

Tags: node.js, node-modules, vite, package.json, lit

I'm having some issues related to vite and serving components "externally" like the dependency is not directly installed.

Im creating my own cli and I want through a custom command serve it with vite but at the same time dont have vite in the component's package.json instead I'm having another package for it:

On one hand this is the component structure where i removed vite dependency to install it later from another package called "package-example":

[image: component image]

Secondly the package example im going to add with its dependencies like vite and typescript:

[image: package example]

At this point in the package folder i use "npm link" or "yarn link" afterwards in the component's folder I add `yarn link "package-example"` to add it, then node_modules starts like this: this is the component with package linked

[image: component with package linked]

Finally i want to execute command vite(through my own cli, but firstly testing it manually) to serve it but it doesnt recognize the command although its inside **node_modules\package-example\node_modules\vite**

Probably I am missing something else, so if anybody could help ne it would be very nice, or if there is a way to extract that subpackage to drop it into the main node_module folder.